# How to get the left ten characters in a data in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to create a view that has the 10 leftmost characters of the date as I do not need the hours, minutes, secs.

I have tried the left query but said that this kind of query was not supported.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generated_date AS
SELECT left("generation_date", 10)
FROM database_final

I expect 2019/02/08 but it is originally 2019/02/08 12:00:00

Answer (score 6):

`SUBSTR("generation_date", 1, 10)` will give you the first 10 characters of a string.

You can find all string functions supported by Athena here: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/string.html